# How to use substring() function to get middle string with relative index?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, substring

I want to extract characters from a string. However, the string doesn't have the same length every time.

Basically I get data from a database and I want extract the value I need in it. But I'm stuck on step where I have to extract the right value.

So first I get data like that :

```vb
 infoDataset2 = accessRequet_odbc("select st_astext(st_snaptogrid(geom, 0.01)) from netgeo_point_tech", myConnection)
```

The result is something like : `POINT(921021.98 6671778.45)`. What I need are the 2 figures, but their length is not fixed. I just want to remove `POINT(` and `)`.

Then I work on each line of the `DataSet` I get to cast each lines into a string with only the value needed.

```vb
For i = 0 To infoDataset2.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            geomPt = infoDataset2.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(0).Substring(geomPt = infoDataset2.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(0).Substring(1 + infoDataset2.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray(0).LastIndexOf("(")))

            Console.WriteLine(geomPt)
        Next
```

This was my last try, where I was able to remove `POINT(` but I'm struggling with the length to cut `)`.

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: Instead of `ST_ASTEXT`, could you use `ST_X` and `ST_Y`? Cf. [Getting coordinates from geometry in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42970/getting-coordinates-from-geometry-in-postgis)

Comment: You could use the `Replace()` function to replace `"POINT("` by `""`, and `")" by `""`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well I can but this is not what I want, as I want to keep a string of X and Y to comparate them to another string. But it might easier and faster to do as you say and merge the two strings. What's you're thought on that ?

Comment: @RobertBaron Yes you totally right. As I'm beggining in VB.Net I didn't know about this function. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be horrible to debug that one long line. It makes no difference to the computer if you split it up into easy-readable parts. Here's some code to get the x- and y-coordinates from a string formatted as shown in the question:

```
Dim s = "POINT(921021.98 6671778.45)"
Dim b1 = s.IndexOf("("c) + 1
Dim b2 = s.IndexOf(")"c, b1) - 1
Dim parts = s.Substring(b1, b2 - b1 + 1).Split({" "c})
Dim x As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(parts(0))
Dim y As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(parts(1))
```

---

Another way of parsing the string is to use a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions), which can be more flexible. In this example, I used named capture groups to make it easy to see which parts are for the x and y:

```
Dim s = "POINT(921021.98 6671778.45)"

Dim x As Decimal
Dim y As Decimal

Dim re = New Regex("\((?<x>[0-9-.]+) (?<y>[0-9-.]+)\)")
Dim m = re.Match(s)
If m.Success Then
    x = Decimal.Parse(m.Groups("x").Value)
    y = Decimal.Parse(m.Groups("y").Value)
Else
    ' Could not parse point. Do something about it if required.
End If
```

Comment: I always use first way, much easier, i kinda hate regex :P

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Morton has given a nice answer, i upvoted that one, if you need an even easier way and that was still complicated use this

```
    Dim s = "POINT(921021.98 6671778.45)"

    Dim part1 As String = s.Remove(0, 6)
    Dim part2 As String = part1.Substring(0, part1.Length - 1)
    Dim split() As String = part2.Split(" ")

    Dim x = split(0)
    Dim y = split(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an even probably easier to understand solution:

```
Dim s as String = "POINT(921021.98 6671778.45)"
Dim coordinate() as String = s.Replace("POINT(", "").Replace(")", "").Split(" ")
```

Enjoy!

Comment: pfff ok you win xD